# Sampling problem: why being able to sample from $P(s)$ and being able to compute $P(a|s)$ implies being able to sample from $P(a)$

Tags: statistics, sampling

I call $P(s)$ a probability distribution for some variable $s$. I call $P(a)$ the probability distribution for some variable $a$.

I have:

$$P(a)=\sum_s P(a|s) P(s)$$

Imagine that I have a computer able to provide me sample $s$ following the probability distribution $P(s)$, and able to compute $P(a|s)$. I am pretty sure I have read somewhere that in such a case, it can provide samples $a$ following the probability distribution $P(a)$  (unfortunately I don't find anymore the source for this: this is kind of "common knowledge" I feel like).

However I do not understand why this is true. Indeed, for me it would only mean that for any $s$, the computer can provide samples following the probability distribution $P(a|s) P(a)$.

But this is not sufficient as we don't have the summation $\sum_s$.

**Hence, my question is:  why being able to sample from $P(s)$ and being able to compute $P(a|s)$ implies being able to sample from $P(a)$**

I am interested by a pedagogic answer but also a reference (like a book) explaining it.

Comment: We don't need summation to sample: if we sample $s_0$ from $P(s)$, and then sample $a_0$ from $P(a | s_0)$, we get the same distribution as if sample from $P(a)$ - just compute probability of getting $a_0 \in A$ for both procedures.

Comment: @mihaild Thanks for your comment. I think this is precisely my confusion: $P(a)=\sum_s P(a|s) P(s)$, hence in the definition of $P(a)$ there is the summation appearing. So for me on one hand I would have $P(a|s)P(s)$ for some $s$ (sampling from $s$ strategy), on the other hand I would have $\sum_s P(a|s)P(s)$ which is different. What is wrong in my explanation? If you could explain precisely this point it would be great!

Comment: Suppose $S \sim N(0,1)$ and, conditioned on $S=s$, you had $A \sim \textrm{Pois}(e^{-s})$.  Then you could simulate values from the marginal distribution of $A$ by simulating values of $S$ and then simulating conditional values of $A$ given $S$ without needing to do any summation or integration.  It does not tell you $\mathbb P(A=a)$ though with a large enough sample you could get close.

Comment: @Henry Could you write an answer for a general proof that the "conditionned" approach gives the same probability for the sample outcomes? This is what I am looking for here. I am confused by the fact the very definitioin of $P(a)$ involves the summation.

Comment: @EasyMan the equality with summation is about probabilities, not sampling. I suggest you to take some simple example - $s$ to be a coin toss, and if it lands head, $a$ is result of 4-sided die roll, and if it lands tail, $a$ is result of 6-sided die roll. And check, for example, probability of $a = 3$, and how you can get it with this inderect sampling procedure.